# Reference error while using flow-typed global variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flow-typed

Newbie into flow-type here. I have global type defined in a `.js` file and it resides in flow-typed folder under the root of my project.

```
// @flow
declare type MCUserID = number;

declare var mcuser: MCUserID;
```

And `[libs]` section my `.flowconfig` looks like below.

```
[libs]
flow-typed
```

But when I try to use mcUser in other modules in the project, I get error
ReferenceError: `mcUser is not defined`.

Am I missing some other configuration? Are the global variables cached somewhere ? I'm using VSCode on windows 7 for development. I read somewhere to restart flow server. I'm not sure how to do that on VSCode. I infact restarted my box and still this doesn't seem to recognize the global declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export your type and variable (in an object `{}`), and then import (or require) them in the modules where you want to use them.